# VTK installation Python : Canopy

Tags: python, vtk, canopy

I have installed VTK on Canopy but when I try to run a VTK Python program, it throws me Error:

```
   import vtkpython
ImportError: No module named 'vtkpython
```

Can Someone tell me Why I am getting this error.

Comment: Without seeing more code we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use VTK's python wrapper, `import vtk`, not "vtkpython".

Better yet, use [`tvtk`](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/tvtk/README.html) or [Mayavi's `mlab` interface](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) rather than using the "raw" `vtk` library directly.

Otherwise, using VTK is going to feel *very* "unpythonic".